# Display thumbnail from Azure AD Graph API in html img

Tags: angular, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I can successfully get what appears to be the png data of a user image but am unable to get it to display in an img element.
(Im getting the data by calling - https://graph.windows.net/{my tenant}/users/{my user}/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6)

I have tried
src="data:image/png;base64,{THE_DATA_HERE}"
but that doesn't seem to work. (Pasting the data here - http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter didnt work either so apparently its not base64)

Any ideas on how to get this result to appear in an img? (This is being done in JavaScript - client side)

I'm using Angular 2 and have to pass the result through the DOM Sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl before it will apply it to the src so perhaps my code isn't quite right yet. Anybody have this working in any browser based client?

Comment: Have you tried to convert the image to Base64 and then show it? Something like `let image = btoa(response.thumbnailPhoto);` and then `src="data:image/png;base64,{image}"` ?

Comment: @cameron Tried that. Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'btoa' on 'Window': The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Comment: Try with `btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(response.thumbnailPhoto)))` I don't know if this will work with .png files.

Comment: No error, but no picture either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with Angular2, however it is easy to use the JavaScript to show the thumbnail based on the Azure AD Graph REST like below:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "https://graph.windows.net/{teantId}/users/user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6", true);
oReq.setRequestHeader("authorization","bearer {access_token}")
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {

var imageUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(oReq.response);
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = imageUrl ;
document.body.appendChild(img);  

};

oReq.send();

})
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Now I just need to map that into Angular 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42076193/angular2-how-to-handle-a-async-image-blob-request looks promising. I didnt see that one that last week.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use a `IStreamFetcher` to request the image. There's a sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console) that does this.

```
        IUser sUser = (IUser) signedInUser;
        IStreamFetcher photo = (IStreamFetcher) sUser.ThumbnailPhoto;
        try
        {
            DataServiceStreamResponse response =
                await photo.DownloadAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("\nUser {0} GOT thumbnailphoto", signedInUser.DisplayName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Program.WriteError("\nError getting the user's photo - may not exist {0}",
                Program.ExtractErrorMessage(e));
        }
```

Comment: I'm not using C#. I'm trying to do this client side in JavaScript (happens to be Angular 2). If there is no way to do it, I suppose I can do it server side (I do have a C# API my client talks to) but for now i'm trying to do this completely in the client. (Updated question to make that clearer)

Comment: @Stephen Ah ok.  You'll have to find a JavaScript library to do this.  [Here's](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/thumbnail) some npm packages that will be helpful. Personally haven't done this in JS so I don't have a good recommendation.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look around a bit next week when I get a chance but I wish I new what exactly I was trying to do, translate from what to base64