# What's the difference between graph.windows.net and graph.microsoft.com?

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to access the users thumbnail photo with `https://graph.windows.net/{teantId}/users/user1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6` (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42447564/display-thumbnail-from-azure-ad-graph-api-in-html-img)). I find nowhere in the graph api docs anything about `graph.windows.net`, but they tell me to go to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/` ([This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#example-1-get-the-photo-for-the-signed-in-user-in-the-largest-available-size)). Can anyone tell me the difference between the two api's? The latter gives me "invalid audience" when I try to access it, so clearly there's a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found out. `graph.windows.net` is the Azure AD graph, and `graph.microsoft.com` is the *Microsoft* graph. I'm trying to access the Azure AD graph, so I want to us `graph.windows.net`. That explains why my token had an `invalid audience` for graph.microsoft.com.

Comment: You should be using Microsoft graph as AAD graph is getting deprecated https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/end-of-support-timelines-for-azure-ad-authentication-library-adal-and-azure-ad-graph/

Comment: I'm not sure how to switch. When getting my JWT token from the app registration it defaults to setting the audience as graph.windows.net. Any insight on how to change would be appreciated :)

Comment: in API permissions, request permissions for Microsoft Graph. Then when acquiring the token, set the audience to `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "When acquiring the token set the audience ...". Is there more app registration settings I need to do? I have the permission for the Microsoft Graph, but the token still says `graph.windows.net`...

Comment: sorry, I meant scope https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.client.confidentialclientapplication.acquiretokenforclient?view=azure-dotnet#parameters